# I do not find "Create Catalog"and"Create Metastore" on Databricks. What do I need to do?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I am trying to set up Unity Catalog in Azure Databricks following this documentation Unity Catalog, but I do not find "Create Catalog"and"Create Metastore" on Databricks.

please help with the setup

Comment: Are you using workspace with Premium SKU? What region are you? Are all requirements fulfilled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started

Answer (score 0):

### Requirements

- Account must be  Azure Databricks account admin.
- Azure Databricks account must be on the Premium plan
- In Azure tenant, must have permission to create:
  -->A storage account to use with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
  -->  A new resource to hold a system-assigned managed identity. This requires that you be a Contributor or Owner of a resource group in any subscription in the tenant.-

> *If any of the above criteria fails, we will be not having access to create metastore*

*If all criteria have been met go through the following reafference [for creating a Unity Catalog metastore]*(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-metastore)